# associate number field with hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of number input fields, labeled small & medium.., and a set of div's with the label small and medium. In my actually project there will be more sizes than just small and medium. When you add a number to the small number input field a text input insertsAfter the div labeled small. When you subtract a number from the small number input field, the text input field that was recently added is removed.

If the small number field is 0, I want

```
<div class="name-number-field-container" data-size="Small">
```

to be hidden, if the small number field is greater than 0 I want the

```
<div class="name-number-field-container" data-size="Small">
```

to show. Same goes for medium.

http://jsfiddle.net/7PhJZ/63/

the hidden and shown is correct, but they are not associated to their proper size and product. all class="name-number-field-container" show

i tried this:

```
$('.product-quantity').on('change', function(){
    var select = $(".name-number-field-container").closest('[id^="product"]').find('[data-size="' + this.name + '"]')
    if($(this).val()>=1){
        $(select).show();
    } else {
        $(select).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you meant?

http://jsfiddle.net/9kXLC/4/

Replace your show/hide code with this:

```
$('.product-quantity').on('change', function () {
    var select = ".name-number-field-container[data-size=" + $(this).attr('name') + ']'
    if ($(this).val() >= 1) {
        $(this).parents('div[id^=product-]').find(select).show();
    } else {
        $(this).parents('div[id^=product-]').find(select).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: this is correct but it still shows the small label in the other product. the number filed is now associated with the size label but it is not associated with the product now

Comment: Okay got a better answer now.  Don't need to edit html either.

Comment: if you have a change there is one more thing wrong with this code but its un related to the show/hide. if you type in 4 in the small (click enter), then type 10 in the small (click enter) it removes all of the name fields why?

Comment: You are comparing strings and not ints `inc = parseInt(val) >= parseInt(old);` http://jsfiddle.net/9kXLC/5/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/fenderistic/Q4bFB/

Basically you have a custom `name` for each `product-quantity` that correlates to a specific `name-number-field-container`'s `data-size`. I had to add the `data-output-id` attribute to distinguish between the different divs. So you use that information to hide or show the correlating `div`s.

```
$('.product-quantity').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).val() >= 1) {
        $(".name-number-field-container[data-size='" + $(this).attr("name") + "'][data-output-id='" + $(this).attr("data-product-id") + "']").show();
    } else {
        $(".name-number-field-container[data-size='" + $(this).attr("name") + "'][data-output-id='" + $(this).attr("data-product-id") + "']").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: the number filed is now associated with the size label but it is not associated with the product now

Comment: @anmaree Ok, I've updated the code, I had to add another custom attribute to do what you wanted.

Comment: it works great in your fiddle but when I try to implement it in my project it doesn't seem to work

Comment: oh because you added a custom attribute out-put... why did you have to do that?

Comment: Make sure to copy and paste the new html as well, I added `data-output-id`'s to the `name-number-field-container`'s

Comment: I had to do that because (from what I could see) there was no other way to distinguish one `name-number-field-container` from another besides looking at their `data-size` attributes, even then you had duplicates, so I need a way to distinguish.

Answer (score 0):

I just added a class to your fiddle that explicitly set the width for the .name-field input class like this: .name-field {width:50px;} and got the results you were looking for.